# Is w3schools a valid resource for learning HTML/CSS/PHP etc

Tags: html, html5

I recently came across [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/) via [html5 Google plus community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/103299867207875326585), and read some things they were saying about [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/). I have not the knowledge to say they are completely wrong, or completely right. They state, and give examples, taken from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/), that they are posting faulty information.

**Question**: *Is w3schools a valid resource for learning HTML/CSS/PHP... still?*

Comment: http://w3fools.com says it all